# Calling a JavaScript function outside of the js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have problems with calling a JavaScript function (which is inside of an object, in it's own .js file) from an other HTML page. In the code exsample I'll just use a simple Hello World function.

```
    //.js file

    window.addEvent('domready',function(){

      var Site = {
        //Here I have like three other functions

        //This function I want to detect the browser version. I use MooTools for this
        detectBrowser : function(){
         if(Browser.ie){
          //Then what ever content goes here
         }
        } 
       }

       //I execute the other three functions here because they need to be called on every page
       Site.dropdownmenu();
       Site.accordion();
       Site.lightbox();
     });
```

I'm working with MooTools so I have wraped everything inside of the domready function.
Now, I want this `cetect` function to execute **only** at one page. I have tried somethink like this:

```
    //In the HTML file between two script tags:
    Site.alert();
```

That does'nt work. Any ideas?
If I execute it in the .js file it works fine. But I don't want it to execute at every page.

Comment: alert is a standard javascript function so call it something else for a start

Comment: You have not posted enough of the code involved for anybody to know what's wrong.

Comment: Please show us a (non-)working example.

Comment: This is what I tried. It does'nt work.

Comment: @Emil I repeat, you **have not posted enough code.** Show us what is surrounding that definition of "Site". Is it inside another function, for example?

Comment: @Emil: did you declare `Site` with or without `var` in the ready function (i.e. `var Site = ...` or as shown above)? As for `alert` being a standard function, as long as you don't declare a global `alert`, you're fine.

Comment: @Pointy  
Yes, i did write var Site = {... I have changed it now :)

Comment: @Emil: which shows you why [sample code](http://sscce.org/) needs to be representative of the actual code. If not, it won't suffer the same issue.

Comment: @outis Sorry, just a regular typing fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable with `var` in a function, the variable is local to that function and inaccessible from outside that function. To make it explicitly global, declare it as a property of `window`:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
    window.Site = ...
```

This isn't necessary for the code to work, it just makes it explicit for programmers that might read your code that `Site` is a global.

Comment: Yes, but I think that, that is the problem. The Site variable is not global. You can only access it inside the Site object.

Comment: Which is why you shouldn't use `var` if you wish to access it outside the function. Not also that [globals are generally bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), though it may be justified in this case.

Comment: I tried to remove the var and replace it with window.Site = {... It still does'nt work. I don't know what's going on

Answer (score 1):

External Javascript files just execute code; the code doesn't know where it's coming from.

As long as your code runs after the external JS file, it will work fine.